# How does compiler infer that Box is borrowing the one which its content borrows?

Tags: generics, rust, reference, lifetime, ownership

```
let s: String = String::from("some message");

let b: Box<&String> = Box::<&String>::new(&s);

drop(s);

let another_box = b; // error! b (which borrows s) is used later!
```

So, above code looks very simple.

`b` is clearly borrowing `s`, in the human sense.

But, I think this is quite magical:
How can the compiler knows that without any lifetime statements?

According to the Rust's standard library,
`Box`'s declaration is as follows:

```
pub struct Box<T, A = Global>(_, _)
    where A: AllocRef, T: ?Sized;
```

And what I think what it really is is as follows:

```
pub struct Box<'a, T, A = Global>(_, _)
    where A: AllocRef, T: ?Sized + 'a;
```

I don't think that the lifetime(or the borrowing) moves automatically for all the situations where a struct has a generic paramter type.
Or is it??

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime is part of the type `T` that's wrapped in the box in this case.

You wrap `&s` of type `&'a String` in the box, where `'a` is an appropriate lifetime of the reference, inferred by the compiler. The type of `b` is therefore `Box<&'a String>`, so it includes the same lifetime parameter. The box itself doesn't need an explicit lifetime parameter – it's generic over an arbitrary type, and there is no reason that type needs to have static lifetime.

This is not specific to a `Box`. For example it works the same way for `PhantomData`, although `PhantomData` doesn't even use its type parameter in any way:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

fn make_phantom<T>(_: T) -> PhantomData<T> {
    PhantomData
}

fn main() {
    let s: String = String::from("some message");
    let phantom = make_phantom(&s);
    drop(s);
    let _another_phantom = phantom;
}
```

results in the same error, i.e. from the viewpoint of the borrow checker, `phantom` borrows `s`, though in reality it doesn't hold a reference to `s`.

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=668e1246ee8b362d05062deac17b35ca))

Comment: Aha! Then, what I guessed in the question was right!

Comment: It automatically gets the lifetime of its generic parameter (which is &'a String), am I right?

Comment: The resulting type `Box<&String>` has  a lifetime parameter, since it contains a reference. I'm not sure what you mean by "it automatically gets the lifetime …" It's more that all references have lifetimes – either explicit or implicit ones.

Comment: I'm quite confused that for all "struct S<T>", S borrows what T borrows. I think there's some kind of counterexample

Comment: @kwonryul I don't think so. I added an example to the answer to show this behaviour isn't specific to `Box`es.